# Install ImageMagick-devel manually

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rubygems, centos, rpm

I'm running into the infamous problem of installing ImageMagick on an RPM based system. After, not surprisingly, finding out that the version available in the repos is too old, I downloaded the available RPM on their website and installed that.

Apparently though its not the `ImageMagick-devel` package that's in the repos, as I'm now getting errors about `Magick-config` not existing. But I have no idea where to download the `-devel` package thats compatible with the much newer version of ImageMagick that I have.

Where is a place that I can download this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by manually building from the source tar.gz. I chose not to use a dev build like @Krishna because that's a bit too bleeding edge.

**Note:** This requires that you uninstall `Imagemagick` and `Imagemagick-devel` from the repositories first.

Installation instructions: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix

I used checkinstall to get an RPM from it so that I can uninstall it later.

Answer (score 3):

**Development Version**

```
svn co https://www.imagemagick.org/subversion/ImageMagick/trunk ImageMagick
```

Comment: Just to let you know, this doesn't work. The sources don't contain the necessary programs.

Comment: na Being RPM land they are all too old or are for Fedora, which I'm not on.